# Even when I assigned controller to a directive the data is fetched from parent controller's scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning AngularJS deirective module.

I am little bit confused about how scopes work when used in directives.

I have written a code please have a look,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Example 6</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\AngularJS\angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\jQuery\jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javaScript">
        angular.module("MyApp",[]);
        (function(){
            angular.module("MyApp").controller("HollywoodCtrl",HollywoodCtrl);
            angular.module("MyApp").controller("BollywoodCtrl",BollywoodCtrl);
            angular.module("MyApp").directive("parentClass",parentClass);


            function parentClass(){
                var obj = {     
                    restrict : 'EA',
                    controller : "BollywoodCtrl",
                    scope: {
                        array : "=bollywoodActors"
                    },  
                    template : "<ol><li ng-repeat='actor in array'>{{actor}}</li></ol>",
                    link : function(scope,element,attrs,someCtrl){  
                        var actorList = scope.actorList, count = 0;

                        for(count = 0;count < actorList.length; count++){
                            console.log(" -+- "+actorList[count]);      
                        }                           
                    }
                }

                return obj;
            };


            function HollywoodCtrl($scope){                 
                $scope.actorList = ["Jim Carrey","Sean Connery","Tom Cruise","Samuel L Jackson","Colin Firth"]                  
            };

            function BollywoodCtrl($scope){
                $scope.actorList = ["Shahrukh Khan","Salmaan Khan","Amir Khan"]                 
            };

        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="HollywoodCtrl">
        <div class="well">
            <b>Bollywood Actors</b>
            <parent-class bollywood-actors="actorList"></parent-class>
            <pre />
            <b>Hollywood Actors</b>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="actor in actorList">{{actor}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Let me explain you what I am trying to do.

I have a controller 'HollywoodCtrl' which is the a parent controller which contains hollywood actor names in array 'actorList' in its scope.

I have a directive 'parentClass' where I have assigned 'BollywoodCtrl' to it,

Now, what I need in the UI is, inside the tag 'parent-class' I want to show bollywood actors present in scope of controller 'BollywoodCtrl',

and outside the directive I need to show hollywood actors present in scope of controller 'HollywoodCtrl'.

But

what I am able to see is hollywood actors present in the parent controller inside 'parent-class' directive and outside it as well.

PLease see the live example here
[Directive Scope live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/yeu2xf5e/5/)

Can you please tell me were I am going wrong,

And how will I get the desired output

Comment: You are passing a variable not using the one into the scope. So when you pass your variable, it's the one from the parent because you are not inside your 2nd controller.

Comment: u passing bollywood-actors to directive and displays it. Change directive tpl to template : "<ol><li ng-repeat='actor in actorList'>{{actor}}</li></ol>" and u see another list.